# Map object properties to comboxbox in WPF mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I'm trying to bind a list to a combo box in WPF but I'm not getting what I expect/need. 
This is what's in my `ViewModel`:

```
public ICollection<FileType> FileTypes { get; private set; }
```

This is my FileType class:

```
public class FileType
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FileAction> FileActions { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm bind my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="uxFileTypeBox"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FileTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileType}"/>
```

The ComboBox is displaying the object instead of its Description, how can I have the ComboBox display the Description property and if possibly use the Code property as the value.

Note: I'm using Toolkit MVVM Light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ItemsSource is bound correctly remove the SelectedItem property and try this:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Description"
```

Edit: You can also add this to use Code as the value.

```
SelectedValuePath="Code"
```